# Sharepoint calculated field formula not working

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-field

I set the following calculated field formula programmatically: 
=SE(Stato_rilievo="evaso";0;1) can you tell what is wrong with the formula as it throews exception saying the formula is not valid.

Comment: <Formula>=SE(Stato_rilievo=&quot;evaso&quot;;0;1)</Formula><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name='Stato_rilievo'/><FieldRef Name='Stato_rilievo'/></FieldRefs>

Comment: this is the fomula that I create programmatically

Comment: the error says "the formula contains a syntax error or is not supported"